# Extract both issue and epic fields in Jira JQL

Tags: jira, jql, epic

I would like to get the following data from Jira:
Issue ID, Issue Summary, FixVersion (from Epic), FixVersion (from Issue).
Any suggestions are appreciated although I would love to not use commercial plugins.
Thanks
Matej

Comment: As far as I know you can query either parent or child and show its fields. But you can query child based on parent fields or the other way around.

Comment: thank you, that would require two queries and some spreadsheet magic. I know how to do that and am trying to find a simpler (JQL) way

Comment: You can use Script Runner plugin for that (they have a free version) and use functions subtasksOf and parentsOf